# Most accurate Enum Constant for RoundingMode (Calculating Pi in Java)

Tags: java, enums, constants

I have written a program that calculates Pi.
It uses `double` types, so naturally it only calculates Pi to a maximum of 16 decimal places in this circumstance.

I'm in the process of trying allow my code to adopt `BigDecimals` types so I can calculate Pi to a more precise figure (i.e. more decimal places).

My progress can be seen [>> here <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134086/calculating-an-answer-in-java-with-more-than-16-decimal-places)

I'm using the `Madhava–Leibniz series` to calculate Pi:

```
     Pi = 4/1 + (-4/3) + 4/5 + (-4/7) + 4/9 + ... + 4/n
```

In my program I do a division like this:

```
     currentTerm=(double)-4/oddTerm;
```

In my updated code, I have changed it to this:

```
    currentTerm = neg.divide(oddTerm, 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

I hope that gives you an idea or what's going on.

My question is, in this example, which **Enum Constant** for **RoundingMode** will be the best to use (or more accurate?)... 
Obviously, Pi's output changes significantly if I use different ones.
Here's a full list:

[image: Java Doc Table]

Also, am I correct is using a `scale` of `10` for this calculation to get the most precision?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
Changed `Scale` to 100; gives Pi to 100dp. etc

Comment: I have no idea why you are using `scale=10`, with a BigDecimal the scale is arbitrary, you could as well use 20 or 100 and get more precision (of course, it will be more slow). Regarding rounding, I'd go with HALF_EVEN, that does'nt have a systematic bias. Anyway, as you are summing term of alternate signs, I guess HALF_DOWN or HALF_UP should perform almost the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have since changed my Scale to 100 (as I wasn't sure what I did until a few minutes ago). Scalle 100 gives me Pi to 100dp. I think I'm going to stick with HALF_UP although I'm questioning my Maths as my program gives `3.14149265359...` and I found on google Pi calculated to 100dp as `3.14159265358...` I'm assuming this is to do with the rounding...?

Comment: You are aware that the Leibniz series converges VERY slowly, are you?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't converge as fast as other methods/series but I figured it would be the easiest to start with. If I can get to a point where I'm happy with the program, I will explore other algorithms :)
My program gives the following for Pi to 1000dp with using 5000 terms: `3.1413926535917932383626433954795001141981798188345532196965187625458916006334194979629989247706731687102838238398361791574536367663058247375248339681750209539995182762289282761350508360315226843520701417644166609500807057357095090492110090220309058886968823519731751091437...` Doesn't look right to me...

Comment: Oh... I just read the `Inefficiency` part of the Wiki Page.. That explains why its `3.14139...` and not `3.14159...` Thanks for highlighting that.. I guess my Maths is correct after all (putting the converging rate to one side)

Comment: To to update anyone who is interested, using 500,000 terms from the Leibniz Series, the program calculates Pi to 10,000 places with 5 'correct' decimals. The proceeding figures are extremely close but obviously still converging. If I had the computing power, I'd use 1000's more terms, but for the purposes of this, I think it's job done :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, read the Javadoc carefully. It contains a lot of examples, how every RoundingMode works.

In real math, we usualy HALF_UP, cause this is how teachers teach us in school. 5.5 rounding to 6. 5.4 rounding to 5.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have already read the Java doc but got a little confused. I thought HALF_UP was the better choice. What you have said is great. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

None. If you're calculating PI to large numbers of decimal places you shouldn't be rounding at all, or scaling either. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: With limited computing power (and knowledge) you HAVE to round to come to a feasible (and some-what accurate) representation. How else is Pi represented at a given number of decimal places if it's an irrational number? Your answer doesn't really make sense.